# Как сделать модель из QAbstractListModel с подгрузкой данных?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, mvc, qabstractlistmodel

У меня есть итератор, неизвестно сколько в нем данных, нужно отобразить их пользователю.

Пусть это будет список. Тогда, думаю, нужно использовать модель [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html).

Знаю, что у моделей есть специальные методы для подгрузки данных: [canFetchMore](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) и [fetchMore](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore)

А как нужно их реализовывать, чтобы модель работала?

Answer (score 3):

Шаги:

- Метод `canFetchMore` должен возвращать булевое значение, отвечающий есть ли еще данные. Т.к. нам неизвестно сколько данных есть, то заведем флаг, пусть будет `self._at_end`. Значение флага будем менять при подгрузке данных в `fetchMore`, когда загрузили всё
- В методе `fetchMore` перебираем итератор через функцию [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), заполняем полученные из итератора данные в список (чтобы модель могла отобразить данные их нужно откуда-то брать, из итератора их уже не взять, т.к. нужно точная индексация, поэтому храним в списке) и ловим исключение `StopIteration`, которое произойдет, когда итератор закончится.
  И обязательно, при получении новых данных нужно вызывать методы [beginInsertRows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) и [endInsertRows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows), чтобы уведомить о новых строках
- Для возврата данных итератора используем метод `data`. Он возвращает данные разных типов и для разных ролей, например, через этот метод можно показать разное значение для отображения (`Qt.DisplayRole`) и при редактировании (`Qt.EditRole`)
- Чтобы представление знало сколько в модели на данный момент строк нужно использовать метод `rowCount`

[Итого:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ab9d5d4d56fe8fe9768c17f4ba525371cb2b65f3/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/model_with_iterator__QAbstractListModel/iterator_list_model.py)

```
from typing import Iterator

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, Qt, QVariant


class IteratorListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, it: Iterator, prefetch=100, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._at_end = False
        self._it = iter(it)
        self._items = []
        self._prefetch = prefetch

    def canFetchMore(self, parent: QModelIndex = None) -> bool:
        return not self._at_end

    def fetchMore(self, parent: QModelIndex = None):
        if self._at_end:
            return

        old_rows = len(self._items)
        for _ in range(self._prefetch):
            try:
                value = next(self._it)
                self._items.append(value)

            # Если данные закончились
            except StopIteration:
                self._at_end = True
                break

        new_rows = len(self._items)
        if old_rows != new_rows:
            self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), old_rows, new_rows)
            self.endInsertRows()

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = Qt.DisplayRole) -> QVariant:
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()

        if index.row() >= len(self._items) or index.row() < 0:
            return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._items[index.row()]

        return QVariant()

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = None) -> int:
        return len(self._items)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    model = IteratorListModel(it=range(1_000_000))
    model.rowsInserted.connect(lambda: mw.setWindowTitle(f'Rows: {model.rowCount()}'))

    mw = QListView()
    mw.setModel(model)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для тестирования модели [накидал пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ab9d5d4d56fe8fe9768c17f4ba525371cb2b65f3/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/model_with_iterator__QAbstractListModel/_more_examples.py) с большим количеством итераторов разного вида:

```
from string import printable
from typing import Iterator

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListView, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout

from iterator_list_model import IteratorListModel


def get_infinity_generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self._add_view_with_it('infinity_generator', get_infinity_generator()))
        main_layout.addWidget(self._add_view_with_it('range(1_000_000)', range(1_000_000)))
        main_layout.addWidget(self._add_view_with_it('list of pow2', [str(i ** i) for i in range(1_000)]))
        main_layout.addWidget(self._add_view_with_it('str', printable * 100))
        main_layout.addWidget(self._add_view_with_it('dict', dict.fromkeys(dir(self))))

    def _add_view_with_it(self, title: str, it: Iterator) -> QWidget:
        group_box = QGroupBox()
        group_box.setTitle('1111')

        model = IteratorListModel(it=it)
        model.rowsInserted.connect(lambda: group_box.setTitle(f'[{title}] rows: {model.rowCount()}'))

        view = QListView()
        view.setModel(model)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(group_box)
        layout.addWidget(view)

        return group_box


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще пример для практического использования методов `canFetchMore` и `fetchMore`.

Как показать количество детей рядом с папкой `QTreeView`?

Чтобы получить количество строк,
это необходимо сделать после вызова метода `fetchMore`.
Все вышеперечисленное должно быть реализовано в делегате.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileSystemModel,
    QStyledItemDelegate, QTreeView,
)


class StyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.column() != 0:
            return
        model = index.model()
        if model.hasChildren(index):
            if model.canFetchMore(index):
                model.fetchMore(index)
            option.text += " ({})".format(model.rowCount(index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QTreeView()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    model = QFileSystemModel()
    model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())

    view.setModel(model)
    view.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.currentPath()))

    delegate = StyledItemDelegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикольно :) Немного не то, но полезно (+1) :)

Answer (score 2):

а как вам официальный пример

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2013 Riverbank Computing Limited
## Copyright (C) 2010 Darryl Wallace <wallacdj@gmail.com>.
## Copyright (C) 2010 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
## All rights reserved.
##
## This file is part of the examples of PyQt.
##
## $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:BSD$
## You may use this file under the terms of the BSD license as follows:
##
## "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
## modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
## met:
##   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
##   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
##     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
##     distribution.
##   * Neither the name of Nokia Corporation and its Subsidiary(-ies) nor
##     the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote
##     products derived from this software without specific prior written
##     permission.
##
## THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
## "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
## A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
## OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
## SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
## DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
## THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
## (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
## OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
## $QT_END_LICENSE$
##
#############################################################################


from PyQt5.QtCore import (pyqtSignal, QAbstractListModel, QDir, QLibraryInfo,
        QModelIndex, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
        QListView, QSizePolicy, QTextBrowser, QWidget)


class FileListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    numberPopulated = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FileListModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.fileCount = 0    
        self.fileList = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.fileCount

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if index.row() >= len(self.fileList) or index.row() < 0:
            return None

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.fileList[index.row()]

        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            batch = (index.row() // 100) % 2
            if batch == 0:
                return QApplication.palette().base()

            return QApplication.palette().alternateBase()

        return None

    def canFetchMore(self, index):
        return self.fileCount < len(self.fileList)

    def fetchMore(self, index):
        remainder = len(self.fileList) - self.fileCount
        itemsToFetch = min(100, remainder)

        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.fileCount,
                self.fileCount + itemsToFetch)

        self.fileCount += itemsToFetch

        self.endInsertRows()

        self.numberPopulated.emit(itemsToFetch)

    def setDirPath(self, path):
        dir = QDir(path)

        self.beginResetModel()
        self.fileList = dir.entryList()
        self.fileCount = 0
        self.endResetModel()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        model = FileListModel(self)
        model.setDirPath(QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PrefixPath))

        label = QLabel("Directory")
        lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        label.setBuddy(lineEdit)

        view = QListView()
        view.setModel(model)

        self.logViewer = QTextBrowser()
        self.logViewer.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred))

        lineEdit.textChanged.connect(model.setDirPath)
        lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.logViewer.clear)
        model.numberPopulated.connect(self.updateLog)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(lineEdit, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(view, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.logViewer, 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Fetch More Example")

    def updateLog(self, number):
        self.logViewer.append("%d items added." % number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Видел такое, хех](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/lazy__qtwidgets_itemviews_fetchmore_example__QAbstractListModel.py#L19) :) Но в этом примере есть нюанс - в `self.fileList = dir.entryList()` мы уже получаем весь список файлов, поэтому подгрузки как бы есть и как бы нет :) Думаю, к моей задаче ближе было использование `QDirIterator`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html#details